# Java volley empty json object

Tags: java, json, android-volley

On a response I expect a JSON string.
But now I have to provide a key for the Object I want to retrieve. The response I want is just simple {"xx":"xx","xx":"xx"} format, without an array with a name like this {"XX":["xx":"xx"]}. How can I fetch the JSON without having to provide a parameter. In short, I just want to read the JSON response I get without having to give a parameter.

```
protected JSONObject parseJSONMeth() {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
                JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(0);
                return jo;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the GSON https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
User result = new User();
result=(gson.fromJson(json, User .class));
```

And for users List :

```
private static List<User> getDataFromJson(String json) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        List<User> result = null;

        try {
            JSONObject posts=new JSONObject(json);
            result = gson.fromJson(posts.toString(), new TypeToken<List<User>>(){}.getType());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```